# SQL SELECT single row for each ID ordered by updated_at column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to select actual data for each campaing from table bellow:

```
+------------------------------+-------------+--------+-----+
| id | updated_at              | name        | status | ... |
+------------------------------+-------------+--------+-----+
| 1  | 2021-01-01 09:00:00 UTC | campaign A  | ACTIVE | ... |
| 2  | 2021-01-05 18:00:00 UTC | campaign B  | PAUSED | ... |
| 3  | 2021-01-10 12:00:00 UTC | campaign C  | ACTIVE | ... |
| 4  | 2021-01-12 14:00:00 UTC | campaign D  | ACTIVE | ... |
| 1  | 2021-01-02 18:00:00 UTC | campaign A  | PAUSED | ... |
| 1  | 2021-01-05 13:00:00 UTC | campaign AA | ACTIVE | ... |
| 2  | 2021-01-17 19:00:00 UTC | campaign B  | ACTIVE | ... |
| 1  | 2021-01-06 09:00:00 UTC | campaign AA | PAUSED | ... |
+------------------------------+-------------+--------+-----+
```

The campaign `id` field is not unique. A campaign's name, status and other omitted columns can be changed over time. Each row represent actual campaign state on update date and time. For example campaign id = 1 was in active state initially, then paused, then renamed and activated, and finally paused again.

Actual state for the specific campaign can be received with `ORDER BY updated_at DESC LIMIT 1` statement, for campaign #1 it will be name = 'campaign AA' and status = 'PAUSED'. But how to receive actual data for each campaign with a single query?

Expected output:

```
+------------------------------+-------------+--------+-----+
| id | updated_at              | name        | status | ... |
+------------------------------+-------------+--------+-----+
| 1  | 2021-01-06 09:00:00 UTC | campaign AA | PAUSED | ... |
| 2  | 2021-01-17 19:00:00 UTC | campaign B  | ACTIVE | ... |
| 3  | 2021-01-10 12:00:00 UTC | campaign C  | ACTIVE | ... |
| 4  | 2021-01-12 14:00:00 UTC | campaign D  | ACTIVE | ... |
+------------------------------+-------------+--------+-----+
```

Thank you.

P.S.: I'm using Google BigQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One standard way of doing this uses `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
SELECT id, updated_at, name, status
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY updated_at DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery has some nifty features that make this pretty simple.  I tend to use `group by` for this:

```
select array_agg(t order by updated_at desc limit 1)[ordinal(1)].*
from `table` t
group by id;
```

This is aggregating by `id`.  The `select` is doing an array aggregation of all the records -- but only keeping one value, and the latest one at that (the `order by` and `limit`).  The rest is just pulling the individual columns from the record.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below option

```
select as value array_agg(t order by updated_at desc limit 1)[offset(0)]
from `project.dataset.table` t
group by id
```